# Xpath - choose the first/second element

Tags: xpath

I have the next xpath:

```
//span[text()="Bingo"]/parent::div/parent::div/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td[1]
```

and it returns two elements.

How I choose one of them (first or second)?

I try:

```
//span[text()="Bingo"]/parent::div/parent::div/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td[1][1]
```

But it still gives me two elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use parentheses over the whole expression, then an index:

```
(//span[text()="Bingo"]/parent::div/parent::div/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td[1])[1]
```

Comment: Thanks. It really finds one element in Xpath Finder, but when I try it on Selenuim IDE, it doesn't find the element